# How does java.awt.dialog achieve modality?

Tags: java, user-interface, awt, modal-dialog

I want to understand how `java.awt.Dialog` achieves modality (blocking other windows)?

Yeah, I tried reading the code of `java.awt.Dialog`, but I am kind of getting lost in it. So I want to know briefly what they do. Do they disable all events of all other windows?

Thanks
Prem

Comment: probably wraps some native libraries into a POJO.

Comment: Since AWT relies on native widgets, it will depend on the underlying toolkit for the actual implementation. On windows for example, this would most likely be through the DialogBox function (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645452%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its system dependent. On windows the main event loop is modified. You are most of the time better off opening a dialog non-modal and lock the underlying window manually (e.g. set a glasspane to the rootpane and disable it, or block all events setting a custom focus manager).

Comment: Could you please explain why is it better to set the modality manually?

Comment: if you suppress events to the application yourself you workaround the trouble with redirected OS main event loops ... however you need some in-depth knowledge of swing to achieve 'pseudo-modality'